# How to delete from dcm4chee-arc server

Tags: mysql, server, ldap, dcm4che

How to delete studies, files and all or some records from dcm4chee-arc server or possibly clean in like fresh new? I've installed version 5 following this [instructions](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Installation). I've used Apache DS as the LDAP server and using mysql as database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UI, there are three, vertical dots. Press that and more actions are available at the study, series, and instance level. The trashcan should reject the instances (i.e. move them to the trash). If you search the trash AE, the trashcan icon is replaced with an X that says "Delete Permanently"

Comment: Wow, that was so easy! I didn't notice there is a second row for each study with another "three dots". The Trash can was visible there. I was removing every records from mysql database! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You might wanna answer it in the following link cause this question would probably soon be removed. https://serverfault.com/questions/902051/how-to-delete-from-dcm4chee-arc-server

Comment: I upvoted because it's so absurd for an excepted answer that is exactly the right solution for OP's problem to have actually negative votes. Dear people, why to downvote something like that?